# Difference between the <a> tag and get request

Tags: node.js, html, get, anchor

I have a perhaps simple question. What would be the difference between an `<a>` tag and a normal GET request with any element. I know the `<a>` tag automatically sends you to the url specified in its `href` attribute. So I assume that a Get request does something similar in it's success callback (as demonstrated below)

But let's say that I also want to send some information along with a normal get request when a for example `<span>` element is clicked on so I write:

```
   $('span').click(() => {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/someurl',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            title: someTitle,
            email: someEmail
        },
        success: (data) => {
                window.location = '/someurl';

        }
    });
});
```

Is there any way to achieve this with an `<a>` tag? Sending information to the server so it's available in `req.query.title` and `req.query.email` ?

Doing the `ajax` request above will run my `app.get('/someurl',(req,res)=>{})`twice because I am sending a GET request to send the data (title and email) and then I am making another GET request when I write `window.location = '/someurl'` How can I redo this so that it only sends the GET request ONCE but also allows for the sending and storing information to the `req` object AND ensures that the browser is now displaying `/someurl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create the appropriate query string in the URL you put in the href of the `<a>` tag and it will work just like your ajax call.  Suppose `someTitle` has the value of `"The Hobbit"` and `someEmail` has the value of `foo@whatever.com`, then you can construct that URL like this:

```
<a href="/someurl?title=The%20Hobbit&email=foo%40whatever.com">Click Me</a>
```

A number of non-letter characters have to be escaped in URLs.  In the above URL, the space is replaced with %20 and the `@` with %40.  In your particular example, you could open the network tab in the chrome debugger and see the EXACT URL that Chrome was sending for your ajax call, copy that to the clipboard and insert it into your `<a>` tag.

Here's a table that shows what characters have to be replaced in a query string component (the part after `&` or after `=`):

[image]

> I'm just wondering then, aside from semantic reasons, is there any other advantages to using an a tag instead of anything else?

`<a>` tags are understood by all sorts of machines that may read your page such as screen readers for the disabled or crawlers indexing your site.  In addition, they work automatically with browser keyboard support, Ctrl-click to open a new tab.  Whereas a piece of Javascript may not automatically support any of that functionality.  So, basically, if the `<a>` tag can do what you need it is widely preferred because it has so much other default functionality that can be necessary or handy for users.

Comment: @JohnSnow - I added info on the additional question you asked in your comments.

Comment: I changed the correct answer because this is a more complete answer, though the other one is also correct .

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="/someurl?title=Hello&email=tom%40home.com">Hello</a>
```

Comment: I'm just wondering then, aside from semantic reasons, is there any other advantages to using an a tag instead of anything else?